# No JSON feed when running on DoubleClick server

Tags: json, flash, actionscript-3, double-click

I have a Flash Ad which makes use of a JSON feed. The Flash file is hosted within DoubleClick Studio.
The call works perfectly locally but when I upload it to DC Studio the load Event.COMPLETE does not file neither do any IOErrors which is leaving me with no feed and no errors!
I have tried making use of the StudioLoader which is supplied by DC which returns that the file is an unrecognised format. Would it be that DC just wont read JSON at all?

```
        request.url = "myJSONFeed.json";
        loader.load(request);
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, decodeJSON);
        loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioError);
        loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatus);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Pretty sure DoubleClick and MediaMind restrict access of remote data and limit you to whatever data is bundled with the ad and accessed with the respective API.

Answer (score 2):

Try placing the `loader.load(request);` after the listeners. Maybe it's firing some events before the listeners are set.